# Can SymPy recognize the derivative of a product?

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math, derivative, calculus

In the program below, SymPy does not seem to understand that the integrand is the derivative of a product. Is there a way to make it return `u*v`?

```
import sympy
x = sympy.symbols('x', real=True)
u = sympy.Function('u')
v = sympy.Function('v')
print((u(x) * v(x)).diff(x).integrate(x))
```

Prints:

```
> Integral(u(x)*Derivative(v(x), x) + v(x)*Derivative(u(x), x), x)
```

Comment: I tried `(u*v).diff(x).integrate(x)` and got the same output.

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: @user6655984 If not possible using built in SymPy functions, I'm also interested in the possibility of extending the `integrate` function to make it possible...

Answer (score 0):

what about `sympy.Derivative(u(x)*v(x), x).integrate(x)`

note that `(u(x)*v(x)).integrate(x).diff(x)` is simplyfied to `u(x)*v(x)`.

Comment: Thanks, but `sympy.Derivative(u(x)*v(x), x)` does not expand the derivative, so it's not really what I'm looking for...

Comment: `Derivative(u(x)*v(x), x).doit()` will expand the derivative as `u(x)*Derivative(v(x), x) + v(x)*Derivative(u(x), x)`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't implemented yet. The comment on [this SymPy issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6958) shows one way you can compute it using `dsolve`.

```
In [4]: solve(dsolve(diff(f(x)*g(x), x) - h(x).diff(x), f(x)), h(x))
Out[4]: [-C₁ + f(x)⋅g(x)]
```